# Centos 7 - replace Perc 6i with H700

Tags: centos, boot, dell-perc, perc6, h700

I've installed Centos 7 using a Dell Perc 6i using 1TB drives. I'm interested in replacing the 6i with a H700 to be able to use larger drives.

I am looking to understand the process so that I can make a decision about whether or not to do this. I would rather not have to re-install everything. I also do not want to have the 6i installed afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been covered pretty extensively over at the Dell Support forums. [This write-up in particular looks fairly straightforward.](https://www.dell.com/community/PowerEdge-HDD-SCSI-RAID/Upgrade-from-PERC-6-I-R-to-H700/td-p/4503508)

Comment: My question is not about the hardware. My question is about Centos itself.

Can I just replace the 6i with the H700 and go about my merry way? Or, are there other steps that need to be done like rebuilding any boot files?

Comment: I see. That wasn’t clear in the original post. As long as /boot and everything stays intact, it should be fine.

Comment: ok. I was able to confirm that the driver used by the controllers is the same.